# Best practice for interrupting streaming async action

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, streaming, cancellation

I am working on an asp.net core controller action that exposes stream for X seconds or until canceled depending on what happens first.

My first approach was to copy stream asynchronously into response, this way I get to use cancellation token rather easily by passing it into CopyToAsync.

```c
[HttpGet]
[Route("getstream1")]
public async Task GetStream1(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var stream = await new HttpClient().GetStreamAsync("http://localhost:4747/video");

    var cst = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);
    var ct = cst.Token;

    Response.OnStarting(() =>
    {
        cst.CancelAfter(5000);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });

    Response.StatusCode = 200;
    Response.ContentType = "video/stream";
    await Response.StartAsync(ct);

    try
    {
        await stream.CopyToAsync(Response.Body, 1024, ct);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex is TaskCanceledException || ex is OperationCanceledException)
        {
            return;
        }

        throw;
    }
}
```

My second idea was to return it as a file stream response and to fire and forget task which awaits given amount of time and aborts HttpContext or is cancelled by user via cancellation token.

```c
[HttpGet]
[Route("getstream2")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetStream2(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var stream = await new HttpClient().GetStreamAsync("http://localhost:4747/video");

    Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000, cancellationToken);

        try
        {
            HttpContext.Abort();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);                        
        }
    }, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            // handle exception
        }
    );

    return new FileStreamResult(stream, "video/stream");
}
```

My question is. Is one of those approaches better that the other in some way? Is there a better way to implement this? Is it ok to call `Abort` on `HttpContext` when I want to end my response?